# LTI system state transition matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having troubling understanding the steps for finding a state transition matrix of a linear time-invariant state space system of the form:

$\begin{bmatrix}
 \dot{x_1} \\
 \dot{x_2} \\
    \dot{x_3}
 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 3 & -3 & 0 \\
    -1 & -1 & -5
 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1 \\
 x_2 \\
    x_3
 \end{bmatrix}  $

I have in my notes that the state transition matrix for an LTI system is simply:

$e^{At}$

where the numerical matrix is A. But I also have in my notes that evaluating $e^{At}$ is not straightforward, but I should instead evaluate it as:

$e^{At} = Me^{Jt}M^{-1}$

Where M is a "modal" matrix (concatenated column of eigenvectors), not really sure what $e^{Jt}$ is but in my notes I have:

$e^{Jt} = \begin{bmatrix}
 e^t & te^t & \frac{t^2e^t}{2} \\
 0 & e^t & te^t \\
    0 & 0 & e^t
 \end{bmatrix} $

So I go through the steps of finding eigenvalues and vectors, apply the form but I am informed that it's incorrect. Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative method 1**: A different method is to use the Laplace transform. If you apply the Laplace transform to

$$\dot{\boldsymbol{x}}=\boldsymbol{Ax}$$

you will obtain

$$s\boldsymbol{X}(s)-\boldsymbol{x}(0)=\boldsymbol{AX}(s) \implies \boldsymbol{X}(s)=\left[s\boldsymbol{I}-\boldsymbol{A} \right]^{-1}\boldsymbol{x}(0).$$

If we apply the Laplace inverse we obtain

$$\boldsymbol{x}(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\left[s\boldsymbol{I}-\boldsymbol{A} \right]^{-1}\right\}\boldsymbol{x}(0).$$

The state transition matrix $\boldsymbol{\Phi}$ is then given by

$$\boldsymbol{\Phi}(t,0)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\left[s\boldsymbol{I}-\boldsymbol{A} \right]^{-1}\right\}$$

---

**Alternative method 2**: You can solve the system explicitly determining the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ (Note, that we have three distinct eigenvalues which are on the diagonal of the system matrix) and eigenvectors $\boldsymbol{v}_i$. The general solution is then given as

$$\boldsymbol{x}(t)=c_1\boldsymbol{v}_1\exp(\lambda_1 t)+c_2\boldsymbol{v}_2\exp(\lambda_2 t)+c_3\boldsymbol{v}_3\exp(\lambda_3 t).$$

The fundamental solution $\boldsymbol{Y}$ is given as the matrix

$$\boldsymbol{Y}(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{v}_1\exp(\lambda_1 t) & \boldsymbol{v}_2\exp(\lambda_2 t) & \boldsymbol{v}_3\exp(\lambda_3 t)\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

The state Transition matrix $\boldsymbol{\Phi}$ is given as

$$\boldsymbol{\Phi}(t,t'=0)=\boldsymbol{Y}(t)\boldsymbol{Y}^{-1}(t'=0).$$

Note, that we have to invert a $3\times 3$ matrix in the second term.

Answer (score 1):

To understand how to solve this problem, first you should learn about the *Jordan normal form*, which is a generalization of diagonalization. Specifically, for any square matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, there exists an invertible matrix $M$ such that

$$
M^{-1}AM = J
$$
where $J$ is a matrix in the following block diagonal form:

$$
J = \left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
J_1 & & & \\
& J_2 & & \\
& & \ddots & \\
& & & J_k
\end{array}
\right]
$$

and $J_i$, $i=1,2,...,k$, called the Jordan blocks, are of the form

$$
J_i = \left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
\lambda_i &1 & & \\
& \lambda_i &1 & \\
& & \ddots &1 \\
& & & \lambda_i
\end{array}
\right]
$$

where $\lambda_i$ is the $i$th eigenvalue, in decreasing order. The number of such blocks is equal to the the dimension of the subspace spanned by the eigenvectors of $A$. Note that $\lambda_i$'s above need not be distinct; the same eigenvalue may correspond to multiple Jordan blocks, and the number of Jordan blocks corresponding to an eigenvalue is the dimension of the subspace spanned by the eigenvectors corresponding to that eigenvalue.

Now, you can use the following property in order to compute $e^{tA}$:

$$
e^{tA} = Me^{tJ}M^{-1}
$$

which can easily be shown using the definition of the matrix exponential. Exponentiating the Jordan form is easy:

$$
e^{tJ} = \left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
e^{tJ_1} & & & \\
& e^{tJ_2} & & \\
& & \ddots & \\
& & & e^{tJ_k}
\end{array}
\right]
$$

where each Jordan block is exponentiated in the following way:

$$
e^{tJ_i} = e^{t\lambda_i}\left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & t/1!& \dots& t^{n-1}/(n-1)!\\
& 1 &\ddots & \vdots \\
& & \ddots &t/1! \\
& & & 1
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Coming back to your example, the $e^{tJ}$ you have in your notes is just the exponentiation of the Jordan form of a $3\times 3$ matrix with the only eigenvalue 1, and eigenspace dimension 1 (note that there is a single Jordan block). The initial matrix you have, on the other hand, has eigenvalues -1, -3 and -5, and linearly independent eigenvectors, hence the Jordan form is simply a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues sitting on the diagonal (Notice how converting to Jordan form reduces to diagonalization for a diagonalizable matrix). Now, you can simply apply the method described above to compute $e^{tA}$.

Comment: if $e^{tJ}$ is a square matrix with $e^{tJ_i}$'s on the diagonal (assuming zero in any other position), AND each $e^{tJ_i}$ is a 3x3 matrix, wont $e^{tJ}$ be a 9x9 matrix? My M is 3 concatenated eigenvectors, so M is a 3x3. I can't solve $e^{tA}$ because I am having matrix-multiplication dimension issues.

Comment: Each $e^{tJ_i}$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix containing the $i$'th eigenvalue for your problem. In general, $e^{tJ}$ is always the same size as $J$, and the dimensions of $J_i$'s sum up to the dimension of $J$.